# Integrate a method with button "touch up inside" action

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a running project and now it is nearly completed but now i have a method in app delegate class and i want that this method should be called on all of the buttons in the project. One simple way is that i should add call to method in each button listener code. 
But is there a way that i can make it wired with Button action "Touch up inside"

Comment: Don't mess with apple code..just write it in every button action

Comment: @NikitaP thats not a great idea at all! Code reusability is something that should be considered always..

Comment: I will sugest you to subclass `UIButton`

Comment: but this will need me to visit each button and change it's class

Answer (score 4):

Override sendActionsForControlEvents by subclassing the UIButton class.

```
- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents {
   if(controlEvents == UIControlEventTouchUpInside) {
      //call your method.  
   }
   [super sendActionsForControlEvents:controlEvents];
}
```

You might have to go through all UIButtons and change its class to that of your subclass. I haven't tried this yet but I think you can give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***extension*** for this

```
extension UIButton
{
    override open func sendActions(for controlEvents:UIControlEvents) 
    {
        if controlEvents == .touchUpInside
        {
           // Type your custom execution here
        }
    }
}
```

This will get called for every event on button

Comment: I tried your solution but for some reason it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

> **swift 5**

```
extension UIButton {
     open override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) {
        //your code
        super.sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
    }  
}
```

I found this as a simplest way to implement a common action for every button click. This is way more simpler than subclassing every button in the app.